# Python: No module named 'X'

Tags: python

I looked through previous answers but nothing helped. I'm running python from what seems to be the correct directory, with all the **init** files, and yet I'm getting the error.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── x_logic
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── # logic sits here
├── dev
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── timings
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── measuring_timings.py
├── ...
```

My command (run from the root folder, ie the one contraining `Pipfile` etc):

```
python dev/timings/measuring_timings.py
```

Result (`measuring_timings.py` is indeed importing from `x_logic`):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x_logic'
```

Same effect with and without `pipenv shell`.

Same effect if try to run immediately from the `timings` dir.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you write code to import `x_logic`?

Comment: Before the import of the failing line, add `print (sys.path)` which will show you the paths used to search for imports, which will give you a clue.  Then try googling "python module import paths" for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend runnring the `measuring_timing.py` as a module, otherwise you will never be able to see the `x_logic` module.

```
$ python -m dev.timings.measuring_timings
```

Comment: Fascinating! I knew about modules but I've never thought about running a normal pythong file this way. Could you explain why this works and the normal way doesn't? I'm at a loss..

Comment: Python is able to to import the modules which are in the sys path. When running the python script as it is a module, the current path is temporally attach to the sys path.